# Cannot instantiate Abstract Type when creating participant or asset in composer-rest-server

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-composer

My model is as follows

```
abstract concept Address {
  o String street
  o String zip
  o String city
  o String country
}

participant Actor identified by userId {
  o String userId
  o String firstName
  o String name
  o Address address
}
```

When I POST a new Actor in composer rest server, I get the following error

> "Cannot instantiate Abstract Type Address in namespace
>   io.mydomain.myapp",

What am I missing out on here ?

Comment: Declare the Address as a normal concept class:    concept Address { ... }  rather than Abstract class.

Answer (score 1):

Abstract types are not meant to be instantiated so no wonder that it can't be created.

Read: https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/reference/cto_language

Specifically this quote is of interest:

> An optional 'abstract' declaration, to indicate that this type cannot
>   be created. Abstract resources can be used as a basis for other
>   classes to extend. Extensions of abstract classes do not inherit the
>   abstract status. For example, the asset Vehicle defined above should
>   never be created, as there should be more specific asset classes
>   defined to extend it.

Consider the Concepts subheading of the docs.

TL;DR: Read the documentation.